# Embedded device: How to do raw reads and write to flash (emmc/movinand) bypassing file system cache

Tags: linux, filesystems, cache, dd, flash-memory

I have an embedded device with a flash memory running linux.
I want to do raw read writes on the flash part but I also want to avoid any file system cache. How can I do this? Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the flash has a filesystem on it and you just want to open a file but bypass the cache for IO to that file, then open it with the O_DIRECT flag.  If it  has no filesystem on it, then you just open the block device directly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the O_DIRECT flag to open().  Be aware that it may not work as expected on the filesystem on your flash device.   Also, I am assuming you are using a filesystem, and not reading a device file.